# Chat info popup position

Tags: feature-request, chat, design

Chat info popup looks odd when the user scroll.

[image]

I clicked that dropdown like button to view the chat info and it appears. But when i scroll while it showing, it won't hide. it is like `position:fixed` thing. This is what i feel odd.

[image]

How about make the popup hide when the user scroll?

any suggests?